# symfony security all hosts except one

Tags: php, security, symfony

```
# app/config/security.yml 
# ...
security:
    firewalls:
        secured_area:
            host: ^admin\.example\.com$
            # ...
```

In symfony, how to have secured area for all hosts except one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should help:

```
security:
    firewalls:
        not_secured_area:
            host: ^admin\.example\.com$
            security: false
        secured_area:
            host: *\.example\.com$
            ## firewall settings go here
```